# parse error on input 'let' Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to store each character from string in list  which i have read from file.so i am doing recursion over list of string called "st" and i="0" to get one string at a time and i am calling this function from my main but i am getting parse error on let and i cant get it. can you figure it out??

```
get' st i=do

if i<(length st)

then print(st!!i)

let j=0

let j=i

let i=j+1

get' st i

else

print ("hi")
```

Comment: Is what you see here *exactly* what you have in your module? Because this code will never parse. Ever. Haskell's syntax is based on indentation (unless you use curly braces and semicolons).

Comment: Can't blame the compiler, I can't parse this either. The indentation is completely broken. Aside from that, it looks like you're missing a `do` in your `then` block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, let's add indentation. Haskell relies on either indentation or curly-braces & semi-colons:

```
get' st i=do
  if i<(length st)
  then 
    print(st!!i)
    let j=0
    let j=i
    let i=j+1
    get' st i
  else
    print ("hi")
```

This still gives the error

```
Temp.hs:4:5: parse error on input `let'
```

Because you need to start a `do` block to chain actions in your `then` clause.

This is a fairly common error for folks new to Haskell. `then` clauses take a single expression. If you want to build a single expression out of a chain of actions, you need a `do`.

So let's add that:

```
get' st i=do
  if i<(length st)
  then do
    print(st!!i)
    let j=0
    let j=i
    let i=j+1
    get' st i
  else
    print ("hi")
```

And now you compile.

There's a bunch of critiques that could improve your code:

- you're recalculating `length st` each time, which makes your code `O(n^2)` in the length of the string. You could calculate it *once* but...
- you'd be better off not calculating it at all, and avoiding `st!!i`, rather deconstructing the list using pattern matching
- this would also avoid your awkward `let j=0; let j = i; let i = j+1; get' st i` (which could be shortened to `let i=i+1; get' st i` or even better `get' st (i+1)`.
- unnecessary parentheses around `length st`, and `"hi"`
- unnecessary `do` in `get' st i=do` - the `if` block is a single expression, so you're not chaining anything together.

Also, you're using `print` which may not do what you want. `print "hey"` prints `"hey"\n` (with quotes) where `putStr "hey"` just prints `hey` (no quotes) and `putStrLn "hey"` prints `hey\n`.

Comment: Didn't know about that, that Haskell concerns about identation. I'm just a learning Haskell. Thanks for the tip!